# Plotting raster cropped to polygon edges in R

Tags: raster, r, graphics

I am trying to produce a map (using R) that uses a color-scale to display raster data.  I want to display the raster data only underneath a particular polygon.  My first thought was to use `raster::mask` to generate a new raster that is cropped to the polygon.  The problem is that, because of the low resolution of the raster, I end up with jagged rather than smooth edges.  Here's an example:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

# Create Raster
r <- raster(ncol=40, nrow=20)
r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r))

# Create Polygon
a <- seq(-150,150,1)
b <- 50*a^2/(150^2)
df <- data.frame(a=a,b=b)
srl <- Polygon(df, hole=as.logical(NA))
Srl <- Polygons(list(srl), 1)
poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Srl), pO = 1:length(Srl), proj4string=CRS(as.character(NA)))

# Plot raster and polygon
plot(r)
plot(poly, add=T)

# Mask and plot
rr <- mask(r, poly)
plot(rr)
```

What I want is something that looks like this instead (this code is clumsy, but it shows what I want; basically it works by plotting a big white polygon on top of the raster with a hole over the area I want visible):

```
# The previous code snippet must be executed prior to this one
e1 <- c(-180,180,180,-180)
e2 <- c(90,90,-90,-90)
df2 <- data.frame(e1=e1,e2=e2)
srl2 <- Polygon(df2, hole=F)
Srl2 <- Polygons(list(srl2), 2)
poly2 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Srl2))
srl3 <- Polygon(df)
Srl3 <- Polygons(list(srl3), 1)
poly3 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Srl2,Srl3))

hole <- poly
polyX <- poly2
coordsHole <-  hole@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords
newHole <- Polygon(coordsHole,hole=TRUE)
listPol <- polyX@polygons[[1]]@Polygons
listPol[[length(listPol)+1]] <- newHole
punch <- Polygons(listPol,polyX@polygons[[1]]@ID)
new <- SpatialPolygons(list(punch),proj4string=poly@proj4string)

plot(r)
plot(new, col="white", border="NA", add=T)
```

In my case, I can't get away with this dumb hack, because the raster needs to be plotted on top of an existing plot.  So how can I plot the raster, where pixels along the polygon edge are partially plotted, so only the parts inside the polygon show?

I don't want to just increase the raster resolution with `raster::disaggregate` for a number of reasons.  The raster is already big to begin with, and it could get pretty unwieldy.  Also, for visualization purposes I want to interpolate the plotted raster (i.e. using `raster::plot(r, interpolate='bilinear')`, and I'm pretty sure `disaggregate` would mess with that.

Note that if I use ggplot2 to plot the raster with `geom_raster`, it handles the edges exactly how I want.  Unfortunately, I need to plot the raster as part of a larger plot for which I cannot use ggplot2.